# Kate (text editor) indentation, c++

Tags: c++, kate

I use the kate text editor for writing c++ code. I really like the editor except for its indentation behavior which drives me mad. I have the following problem: If I want to write code like

```
if( true )
{
    //code
}
```

the indentation messes everything up initially: instead of inserting a tab and jumping to the position marked "`//code`" when hitting enter, kate just inserts a single blank space. So to describe it more in detail: You start from

```
if( true )
{//your cursor is here
}
```

and on pressing enter, kate produces something like

```
if( true )
{
[ ]//your cursor is here
}
```

where '[ ]' stands for a *single* blank space. But instead, I want kate to insert a tabulator to give the result indicated at the start. Or, to repeat it more verbosely, I want that kate gives me

```
if( true )
{
<tabulator>//your cursor is here
}
```

on hitting enter. I have played around with all settings and can not make it work. It drives me crazy. I selected "default identation mode normal", "Ident using tabulators" (8 characters). Does anybody know how to customize this behavior? I looked up the katerc file but couldn't find any options that would help me...

**edit**: I should add that it would be ok if kate would just give me

```
if( true )
{
//your cursor is here
}
```

on pressing enter. But this additional blank space is absolutely annoying.

Comment: I used kate in a galaxy far far away and it was behaving correctly regarding indentation. So there must be an option you missed. Should be something like smart indent, or smth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I tried for half an hour, I don't know why I found out how to do it right AFTER posting the question :). So in case anybody has the same issue, here is the "solution": I missed that kate seems to have a global setting for the indentation mode as well as a *local* one for every file. In my case - for some reason - my file had special indentation options set. You can alter them via the menu bar by chosing "Tools -> Indentation". This local option overrides the global one! Or the global one is just the default for the local options, I don't know exactly...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a config file `.kateconfig` and add the variables `kate: replace-tabs off; tab-indents: true;`

More on this in the [manual](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/applications/katepart/config-variables.html).